# What does "収まり悪い" mean?

Tags: translation

Like in here. https://blog.goo.ne.jp/osibanaokaasan777/e/111153ca9b808e6aeac2dc187b10beb2

and here. https://gramho.com/explore-hashtag/%E5%8F%8E%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84

Why is 悪い on the end here? Is it like saying 悪い to to say sorry?

Comment: a bad/mismatched picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

収まる means "to settle", "to (comfortably/neatly) fit into something", etc. 収まり is its noun form, and 収まり悪い is an i-adjective made by combining 収まり and 悪い ("bad"). Therefore 収まり悪い, literally meaning "bad-settling/fitting", describes that uneasy/uncomfortable feeling you have when something is set in a slightly wrong place or situation. The "place/situation" can be a physical container, a camera frame, a social position, or even a solution to a problem. Simply put, 収まり悪い is a way to say "kinda uneasy/uncomfortable/messy/out-of-place".